# Download file to remote server using WSL

Tags: linux, download, remote-access, wsl2

I want to download a large file onto a remote server that I am connected to using WSL2 on my Windows system. I don't want to download the file to my local Windows machine but directly onto the server that I am connected to. Is there any way of doing it using a link?
I am connected to server via SSH and I want to download XYZ.zip file in that server (I dont know if now thats called upload or download). But simply I want my file in certain folder of that server. And it is linux server.
I have zero idea about linux so please pardon me!

Comment: Welcome to Super User!  I'm assuming that you are "connected to" the remote system via SSH?  If so, could you [edit](https://superuser.com/q/1759051/1210833) your question to clarify and confirm?  There are multiple ways that you might be "connected" to a remote system using WSL.  Would also be worth providing details on the type of the remote system you are using -- Assuming it is Linux, but also worth confirming.  Thanks!

Comment: By download, do you mean "upload"?  Your question is difficult to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`wget` is most likely what you need if you want to download the file from an external source (this is implied by the link you mentioned).

Since you are using wsl to connect to it, I assume the remote server is a linux machine. In this case wget is probably already intalled there. If it is not, you can install it with the package manager appropriate for this distribution.

Comment: That is assuming the WSL2 machine has a webserver installed and is reachable from the remote host. That's a big assumption.